# how to get a token in js webapp for bearer-only backend client

Tags: oauth-2.0, keycloak, bearer-token

I got this setup for my app:

1. Keycloak server
2. Keycloak-protected nodejs backend (bearer-only)
3. PHP/Reactjs frontend

The frontend is optionally login-protected. For some users it will be required to login which will redirect the user to Keycloak server. After a user is logged in, the frontend will have a bearer token to make api calls to the keycloak-protected backend.

My problem is how to get a bearer token for users that don't need to be logged in (anonymous users).

I tried this approach:

1. Created "confidential" client to be used by PHP.
2. Frontend PHP gets a bearer token using client_id and client_secret and passes them to javascript (by that I mean, printing out token values inside  tag which is a global variable)
3. Initially, the frontend makes successful api calls because the access_token passed by php is fresh/valid.
4. After the access_token is expired, I will need to fetch a new one using refresh_token.
5. But, for that I need client_secret which is not available in the js app (and it's not recommended to save client_secret and password in js app, as you know).

I'm stuck here. I researched, read a lot of documentation, but failed to find a way to achieve that.

One other idea that crossed my mind was to make the bearer access_token long-lived (1 hour, for instance). But, some users may use the app for more than an hour.

At this point, I'm not sure, if it's possible to make anonymous calls to keycloak protected backend from javascript web app.

Is it wrong to have very long lived (for example, 6 hours) access_tokens? What other options do I have?

Answer (score 2):

I have come across a similar situation. You can use following approach.

- Your API is always protected by access tokens
- Initially, your PHP backend retrieve an access token using **[Client Credentials Grant](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/3.3/server_admin/topics/sso-protocols/oidc.html)**
- Once UI is loaded, you make a JS call to PHP backend and obtain the correlated access token. You store it to **local-storage**
- This call is protected by session. Initially it's unauthenticated/anonymous access
- In case you need access tokens with different scopes (scopes only granted for logged in users, non anonymous case), then you make your end user follow a log in process to obtain new tokens
- Once tokens are received, you again store them against the session you have with backend and front-end
- UI can obtain the access token to front end through the same backend call

This way you does not hard code access token values to your UI code. Also, backend calls are protected by session.

Additionally,

- Refresh token is stored in backend. So it is safe to store and refresh
- Client credentials are never exposed to front end

Only burden is the session maintenance with backend. But there are many best practices that are built around this .!

Answer (score 1):

Without adding a lot of complexity, When the access token has expired (user unauthorized request), redirect the user to log back in.  This is much much easier because it is the same flow for many scenarios.

The other option is to use something like a session to handle this, which REALLY increases the complexity.  https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-session-1_0.html

Comment: My problem is anonymous access. Some visitors may not register, but they should still be able to use our app. Registered users can update access token when it's expired; no issue there.

Comment: Cool, in that case would definitely follow the first one of sending them to login page.  Send a 401 to the client when they do not have credentials or need to re-request credentials then handle that code on the client by navigating them to login.